# domain of convergence of series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2(2z−1)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I need to find domain of convergence of series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2(2z−1)^n$.
What I did is I take $2^n$ out like $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2 2^n(z−1/2)^n$.
Let $z_1=z-1/2$ make the series like $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n^2 2^n(z_1)^n$.
Then I let $c_n=n^2 2^n$ and found $R=1/2$. So domain of convergence for $z_1$ is $D(0,1/2)$. If I want to translate it to $z-1/2$ is it like shifting the ball to the right by 1/2 on the real axis  like how we did it in $\mathbb{R^2}$ and $D(1/2,1/2)$?

Is my reasoning correct? Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct but you could use the ratio test from the begining.
Put
$$u_n=n^2(2z-1)^n$$
then

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}=|2z-1|$$

So
$$|2z-1|<1\iff |z-\frac 12|<\frac 12\implies \sum u_n \text{ converges}$$

and

$$|2z-1|>1\iff |z-\frac 12|>\frac 12\implies \sum u_n \text{ diverges }$$

we conclude that $ R=\frac 12$.

Comment: How did you conclude that |2z-1|<1 and conclude that it converges?. I didn't understand that part.

Comment: @Mrnobody I did not conclude that. the ratio test says that if the limit is $<1$, the series converges.

Comment: now I understand thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

Using the $n$-th root test one gets convergence fo al $z$ such that
$\lim_n\sqrt[n]{n^2}|2z-1|=2|z-1/2|$, that is for all $z$ inside  the circle centered at 1/2 and radius $1/2$

Comment: thank you very much!